# How To Toggle Airplane Mode in Windows 8 from CMD or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, command-line, windows-8.1

After reviewing multiple posts on the internet, I still cannot find a solution that will allow me to toggle AirPlane mode for Windows 8 from either CMD or PowerShell.

Does anybody have a solution that expressly uses either of these options?

Comment: Here's one alternative: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/24541-airplane-mode-off-shortcuts-create-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @paulsm4 the url http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/24541-airplane-mode-off-shortcuts-create-windows-8-a.html I was aware of, but I wanted specifically a command that can be run from the powershell, or CMD, as it needs to be run remotely without getting up a whole desktop each time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to toggle the airplane switch.  But you can easily turn off all your radios using powershell in windows 8 using the [Network Adapter Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134956.aspx)

Use `Get-NetAdapter` to see all your adapters, bluetooth\wifi\ethernet

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

You can disable a specific adapter by its index\name\description:

```
Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi"
```

Or you can just disable them all like so:

```
Disable-NetAdapter *
```

And turn them back on

```
Enable-NetAdapter *
```

**Note:** You will need to run Powershell as admin to execute the `Disable-NetAdapter` and `Enable-NetAdapter`

Comment: C:\>powershell.exe -Command "Enable-NetAdapter *" and the opposite seems to work for me. :-)

Comment: Add `-confirm:$false` if you don't want to confirm.  (in cmd: `powershell.exe -Command "Enable-NetAdapter *" -confirm:$false` )

Comment: This disableds the interfaces in windows, which is not the same as turning of radio.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution is:

```
get-netadapter wi-fi | restart-netadapter
```

Comment: Note that this requires admin privileges